# Fixed position sidebar that moves when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, layout, css-position

So, I have this pretty basic layout, really just experimenting to see if I make this work.

http://jsfiddle.net/PZP8p/

Here's some code (that's the same as the jsfiddle)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Layout Test</title>


        <style type="text/css">


        body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }



        .header {
        height: 150px;
        background-color: aqua;
        }

        .main-content {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 240px;

        }


        .left {
        width: 220px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: red;
        position: fixed;
        top:150px;
         -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
         -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
         -o-transition-duration: .2s;
         transition-duration: .2s;
         overflow: scroll;
        }

        .center {
        background-color: blue;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 300px;
        float: left;
        }

        .sidebar {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        right:0;
        background-color: green;
        float: left;
        }


        @media screen and (max-width:1150px) {
        .left {
        width: 80px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        position: fixed;

        }
        .main-content {

        margin-left: 100px;

        }   

        .center {
        margin-right: 200px;


        }   

        .sidebar {
        width: 200px;

        }


        }

        </style>



    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>

        <div class="left">

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>

        <div class="main-content">

            <div class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

            <div class="sidebar"></div>


        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's like, left sidebar, center content, right sidebar and a header at the top.

What I'd like to do is to is have the left and right sidebars be 150px from the top (the height of the header) then as you scroll down to the header they're 10px from the top.

This page is a perfect example of what I want to do.
http://readwrite.com/2013/02/05/why-jailbreaking-ios-6-is-popular-enough-to-break-cydia

It's like it gradually moves closer to the top, pixel by pixel as the user scrolls down.

I'm thinking jquery somehow?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is done with the help of JQuery you have to include JQuery in your html file and here is the function:
here is the link of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/xDfya/
or you can add this code
    
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {

```
        $('.left').css({
            position:'fixed',
            top:'0',
            left:'0',
            right:'0',
            'z-index':'999999',
        })
    } 
    else {
        $('.left').css({
            position:'fixed',
            top:'150px'
        })

    }
});
</script>
```

you can do whatever you want in this if or else condition and let me know if you have any problem

Comment: I know how to do what you posted, that's just changing the CSS with jquery.
What I want to do (as in the link to readwrite.com I posted) is have it SMOOTHLY move with the page as the user scrolls down.

Comment: yes i have seen that website and for similar that function you can use animation i've just show you how you can do that things

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to detect scroll position, and if the element hits the desired y position, add a pixel to a style.top for every pixel scrolled down (making it appear fixed after the user has scrolled past the header).

In order to do this, you have to add an id to the section that will scroll a bit before appearing fixed, and add the javascript that measures the scroll and positions the id.

I re-worked the html above to a more conventional 3-column layout with fixed right and left widths, and a fluid center content area.

The relevant javascript is below, and here's a [jsFiddle **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/deborah/vAnh5/)...

```
function fixTop() {
  // get scroll distance
  function getScrollY() {
    var y = 0;
    if( typeof ( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
        y = window.pageYOffset;
    } else if ( document.body && ( document.body.scrollTop) ) {
        y = document.body.scrollTop;
    } else if ( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollTop) ) {
        y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return [y];
  }  

  var y = getScrollY();
  var y = y[0];

  // tell it which element has to scroll, then stick
  var fixMe = document.getElementById('left' );

  // measure distance and fix it at the correct scroll position  
  function getYset() {

      // tell it how far it has to go before fixing
      var scrollToHere = 200;

      // check where it is and provide the style.top value
      if (y > scrollToHere) {
        ySet = y - scrollToHere;
        return [ySet];
      } else {
        ySet = 0;
        return [ySet];
      }
  }

  var ySet = getYset();
  var ySet = ySet[0];

  //  set the style.top according to the calculations above
  fixMe.style.top = ySet + "px";
}

// run the function when user scrolls
window.onscroll = function() {
  fixTop();
}
```